# How can i block a user account in symfony 6?

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin, symfony6

Im using symfony 6 and easyadmin 4.
Im trying to figure out how to block a user account on my website but
i can't find a solution.

I tried to create a role named: ROLE_BLOCKED and then use a function like IsDenied in the controllers to block the access but it seems like they are no such function in symfony 6.

update:
here is my LoginAuthenticator

```
class LoginAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    public function __construct(private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('email', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example:
        // return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

and my security.yaml:

```
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\RegisterAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    role_hierarchy:
            ROLE_ADMIN:   ROLE_USER
            ROLE_ARTIST:  ROLE_USER

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
         - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

**FINAL UPDATE: I solved the problem by using a userChecker CLass**

Comment: Don't you have `active/inactive` status?

Comment: @urfusion no i dont think so

Comment: Create a `status` column in DB. When status `active` or `1` you can allow user and when `inactive` or `0` you can block user.

Answer (score 0):

use `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security` to get user details and add condition based on the status. or you can directly use `isEnabled` method

```
public function isEnabled() {
    return $this->getIsActive();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you need to:

1. Store users status (able to connect or not)
2. Prevent user from logging in
3. Be able to disable an user with EasyAdmin

---

To enable/disable users, you could just add a new `$isEnabled` property:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default":true})
 */
private bool $isEnabled = true;

public function isEnabled(): ?bool
{
    return $this->isEnabled;
}

public function setIsEnabled(bool $isEnabled): self
{
    $this->isEnabled = $isEnabled;

    return $this;
}
```

*Don't forget to update your schema (with a new migration)*

---

To prevent your user from logging in, if you are using the new authenticator system (5.3+) you could just update your getUser method and add something like:

```
if (!$user->isEnabled()) {
    // fail authentication with a custom error
    throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Account is disabled.');
}
```

---

And finally just add your new isEnabled boolean to your crud controller:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
   //...
   yield BooleanField::new('isEnabled');
}
```

Comment: ok I'll try this and let you know if it works

Comment: the method getUser doesn't work

Comment: Do you have an authenticator to handle login ?

Comment: yes i do but i can't use the isEnabled function

Comment: Update your question with more information, your security.yaml and LoginAuthenticator would help a lot

Comment: i solved the problem by using a UserChercker Class